# Ошибка Error converting bytecode to dex

Tags: java, android

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
```

Судя по ошибке нужно добавить targetCompatibility и sourceCompatibility в gradle. Каким образом можно это сделать? Если можно приведите пример, пожалуйста.

Gradle файл

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('sqljdbc42.jar'))
android {
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В build.gradle своего модуля надо добавить

```
android{
......
    compileOptions{
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```

Comment: А можно поподробнее, что-то не получается. Вот мой gradle configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('sqljdbc42.jar'))
android {
    compileOptions{
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
} Получился такой gradle только строчки compileOptions,  targetCompatibility и sourceCompatibility подчеркивается и выбивает ошибку Gradle DSL method not found: android()

Comment: Это надо прописывать именно в build.gradle модуля, а не в файле проекта(у вас их два там, один помечен как Project:project_name, а второй Module:app)

Comment: Дело в том, что прописал в файле gradle модуля

Comment: @КириллАвдеев А выложите нутро файла в пост. В комментариях совершенно невозможно читать. Но в целом ошибка наталкивает на мысль о синтаксической ошибке. Градл обычно примерно так на них реагирует

Comment: обновил вопрос, прикрепил gradle файл модуля